# Find distance between 2 lat and lon point. I have used the formula but answer is not what you expect

Tags: java

```
public double distance(double x, double y, double x2, double y2) {
    // r is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
    double r = 6371e3; 
    double toMile = 0.000621371;
    double latDiff = x2 - x;
    double lonDiff = y2 - y;

    // a is the square of half the chord length between the points
    double a = (Math.sin(latDiff/2) * Math.sin(latDiff/2)) + (Math.cos(x) * Math.cos(x2) * Math.sin(lonDiff/2) * Math.sin(lonDiff/2));

    // c is the angular distance in radians
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

    // d is the distance between to points
    double d = r * c * toMile;

    return d;
}

System.out.println(distance(41.386263640000003, -81.494450689999994, 42.531041999999999, -82.90854831));
```

This print statement gives me 4148.871894445495 miles whereas I checked through google map its distance is 193 miles. Can someone explain why is this so.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking us if you're using the right formula? If so, then show us where you got that formula. --- Are you asking us if you correctly implemented the formula? If so, show us the formula you implemented, so we can compare it to the code. --- In short, show us the formula you're basing this code on.

Comment: Do it on paper - then debug and compare each step of your program to what you did on paper and find where the differences begin and maybe you can then ask a more specific question. If you cannot do it on paper then the issue is not with the programming - the problem is with math.

Comment: @Andreas [link](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) this is where i found the formula.

Comment: Edit the question and add link to clarify the question. Also, explain why you say distance is 193 miles, when that link says it is 172.8 km, aka 107.4 miles, which also fits 173 km distance calculated on https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between degrees and radians? That may be playing a part here.

Comment: @csmckelvey yes, file that I am getting data from has radians value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you forgot to convert to radians :

```
 public double distance(double x, double y, double x2, double y2) {
        // r is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
        double r = 6371e3;
        double toMile = 0.000621371;
        double latDiff = (x2 - x)*(Math.PI)/180;
        double lonDiff = (y2 - y)*(Math.PI)/180;;

        // a is the square of half the chord length between the points
        double a = (Math.sin(latDiff/2) * Math.sin(latDiff/2)) + (Math.cos(x) * Math.cos(x2) * Math.sin(lonDiff/2) * Math.sin(lonDiff/2));

        // c is the angular distance in radians
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

        // d is the distance between to points
        double d = r * c * toMile;

        return d;
    }
```

Have a look here : https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html